# SEVERE: Unable to start Cucumber Error When I Tried to Run Feature File

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, feature-file

I Just created the Feature file and POM and I tried to run feature file as Cucumber Feature but it displaying error as below, please tell me what i need to do? I Installed Cucumber plugins , I Used Latest version of Cucumber 6.10.2, where I am doing mistake i do know please help me to resolve this. Then I Checked the Feature path also that was correct , I tried to run with Run configuration in that i set the correct path for feature file even thought it is correct same error is displaying?? I Uninstalled and installed many times and tried not yet got the solution.

This the Console Error what i Am getting

```
SEVERE: Unable to start Cucumber
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:39)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:33)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.createRunner(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.get(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getRunner(CucumberExecutionContext.java:128)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:115)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Mar 27, 2021 12:20:49 AM io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime run
SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:93)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:39)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:33)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.createRunner(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.get(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getRunner(CucumberExecutionContext.java:128)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:115)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    ... 3 more


0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.237s


?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
? Share your Cucumber Report with your team at https://reports.cucumber.io          ?
? Activate publishing with one of the following:                                    ?
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? Environment variable:                            CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    ?
? JUnit:                                           @CucumberOptions(publish = true) ?
?                                                                                   ?
? More information at https://reports.cucumber.io/docs/cucumber-jvm                 ?
?                                                                                   ?
? Disable this message with one of the following:                                   ?
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
Exception in thread "main" io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getException(CucumberExecutionContext.java:82)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:103)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH.
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:39)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:33)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.createRunner(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SingletonRunnerSupplier.get(SingletonRunnerSupplier.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getRunner(CucumberExecutionContext.java:128)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:115)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$execute$6(Runtime.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$2(Runtime.java:86)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Welcome Rama! Your question is looks horribly formatted. I am sure that was a mistake. Please don't overuse headings. So [edit] and also provide your POM file, so we can reproduce .. the feature-file might help optionally.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution after One Week of trying to solve this error, with gods grace I found one solution in Web for different issue, but I tried it for my issue,

Just go to .m2 folder >> Repository >> delete all the files
Then in eclipse Project >> clean >> All project

Then run the project got success